# Tags Not Being Deployed to Server Farm with Azure ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-automation, azure-resource-manager

**EDIT 11/15/2016**: This was a bug in Azure which was fixed a couple of days ago.

---

Original post:

I'm trying to create several app services which depend on a server farm. I'm using an ARM template to deploy it. I'm using the same tags and tag format on every other resource in the template and they are getting created, but for some reason the tags on the server farm aren't. I can create the tags on the server farm through the Azure Portal and the Resource Explorer, but not through the ARM template.

Here's part of my resources section:

```
{
    "comments": "",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
    "sku": {
        "name": "S3",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "size": "S3",
        "family": "S",
        "capacity": 1
    },
    "tags": {
        "tag1": "[parameters('tag1Value')]",
        "tag2": "[parameters('tag2Value')]",
        "tag3": "[parameters('tag3Value')]",
        "tag4": "[parameters('tag4Value')]",
        "tag5": "[parameters('tag4Value')]",
        "tag6": "[parameters('tag6Value')]",
        "tag7": "[parameters('tag7Value')]"
    },
    "name": "[variables('serverFarmName')]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('serverFarmName')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": 1
    },
    "dependsOn": []
},
[...]
```

Any known issues with this? Do I have the tags in the wrong place?

**Edit 8/8/2016**:
Deploying just a server farm works correctly, but as soon as I add a site to that server farm the tags aren't deployed correctly. Here's what happens: Deployment starts, the *server farm* is created. Before the *site* is created I can rush into the Azure portal and see the tags created correctly on the *server farm*. As soon as the *site* is created I refresh, go back into the *server farm*, and the tags have disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine on my side, you can try to leverage the Azure Resource Group project in Visual studio as mentioned at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2015/11/22/creating-arm-templates-with-azure-resource-explorer/.

Here is my simple test template for your information:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "tag1Value": { "type": "string" },
    "tag2Value": { "type": "string" },
    "tag3Value": { "type": "string" },
    "tag4Value": { "type": "string" },
    "tag5Value": { "type": "string" },
    "tag6Value": { "type": "string" },
    "tag7Value": { "type": "string" },
    "garysfName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "garysfSKU": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Free",
        "Shared",
        "Basic",
        "Standard"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Free"
    },
    "garysfWorkerSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "0"
    }
  },
    "variables": {
    },
  "resources": [
      {
          "name": "[parameters('garysfName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
          "dependsOn": [ ],
        "tags": {
          "displayName": "garysf",
          "tag1": "[parameters('tag1Value')]",
          "tag2": "[parameters('tag2Value')]",
          "tag3": "[parameters('tag3Value')]",
          "tag4": "[parameters('tag4Value')]",
          "tag5": "[parameters('tag4Value')]",
          "tag6": "[parameters('tag6Value')]",
          "tag7": "[parameters('tag7Value')]"
        },
          "properties": {
              "name": "[parameters('garysfName')]",
              "sku": "[parameters('garysfSKU')]",
              "workerSize": "[parameters('garysfWorkerSize')]",
              "numberOfWorkers": 1
          }
      },
  {
      "name": "[variables('garyarmwebappName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [
          "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('garysfName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
          "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('garysfName'))]": "Resource",
          "displayName": "garyarmwebapp"
      },
      "properties": {
          "name": "[variables('garyarmwebappName')]",
          "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('garysfName'))]"
      }
  }

  ],
    "outputs": {
    }
}
```

And the parameters JSON file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "tag1Value": { "value": "tag11" },
    "tag2Value": { "value": "tag22" },
    "tag3Value": { "value": "tag33" },
    "tag4Value": { "value": "tag44" },
    "tag5Value": { "value": "tag55" },
    "tag6Value": { "value": "tag66" },
    "tag7Value": { "value": "tag77" },
      "garysfName": {
          "value": "garyserverfarms"
      }
  }
}
```

And you can refer to https://ms.portal.azure.com/?flight=1&flight.browsegrid2=true&flight.pov2=true&flight.resourcemenuperf=true#blade/HubsExtension/SubscriptionTagsListBlade to check the tag list on Azure portal.

Comment: There's definitely something weird going on here - it may be a bug. Deploying just the server farm works correctly, but as soon as I add a site to that server farm the tags aren't deployed correctly. Here's what happens: Deployment starts, the _server farm_ is created. Before the _site_ is created I can rush into the Azure portal and see the tags created correctly on the _server farm_. As soon as the _site_ is created I refresh, go back into the _server farm_, and the tags have disappeared.

Comment: I added a website template in it, but it still worked fine on my side, refer to my update. Could you please tell how to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I narrowed it down to just having a server farm and then a site, as your updated example shows. I still get the tag issue when deploying the template. I've actually opened a support ticket and they are engaging operations so I'll update here when I hear back.

Comment: Ok, looking forward to your news

Comment: It was confirmed as a bug and scheduled into the Microsoft backlog. I'll update again when I hear more news.

Comment: The fix was released to Azure a couple days ago and I've confirmed it. Behavior should be working as expected now.